# Is there any way to have such a double border on button in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have to make a button with double borders as shown on the image bellow. Is there any way to make it with double border without adding additional xaml elements except the button.

[image]

Comment: Did the below answer work for you? if so can you mark it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the latest versions of XF that should be fairly easy to do (make sure you optimize this code for your usage):

Create a border-style:

```
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10" />
            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="2" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Fill"/>
            <Setter Property="StrokeShape">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="10" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Once done use it as below:

```
<Border Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="5" Padding="8" BackgroundColor="White">
  <Button BackgroundColor="Blue" Text="Submit"/>
</Border>
```

To add events to this whole view you might have to set the button's InputTransparent property to `True` and then add a Gesture to the whole View

Once done it would look like the image below:

[image]